# How to select the label of an <option> given its value, and given a name for the <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the following code:

```
<select name='starttime' onChange='cells(this);'><option value='1'>2004Q1</option><option value='2'>2004Q2</option></select>
<select name='endtime' onChange='cells(this);'><option value='48'>2015Q4</option><option value='47'>2015Q3</option></select>
```

How can I access the text of say, the option with value = 1 of the "starttime" `<select>` (i.e. 2004Q1)? I can access the value of this element by using the following jQuery code:

```
$('[name=starttime]').val()
```

However, I'd like to instead specify a value and name, and get the associated text.

Comment: What do you mean by "label"? No `<label>` element appears at `html` at Question.

Comment: I apologize, I mean the text associated with an option. (i.e. the "label") Also you can ignore the word <div>, I just mean the <select>.

Comment: `.textContent` is not a "label" that am aware of. Can you link to documentation of `<option>` `.textContent` referenced as "the "label""?

Comment: I am using the word label as a colloquial term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```js
console.log($('[name="starttime"] [value="1"]').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="starttime">
  <option value="1">2004Q1</option>
  <option value="2">2004Q2</option>
</select>

<select name="endtime">
  <option value="48">2015Q4</option>
  <option value="47">2015Q3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Note, `cells` function is not defined at stacksnippets

Comment: To be honest, I just answered to the specific point raised in the question. I did not refactor the HTML code which is completely invalid. `<select>` elements are not even closed, by the way...

Comment: Well, at least you are honest. How will a partially complete Answer help OP completely as to the Question? Though granted,  the Question is incomplete.

Comment: It's 03:21 AM in France, I'm a bit tired... ^^ However, I modified my answer to include a clean HTML code.

Comment: Sorry, I did not end the select tag because I only copied a portion of the code!

Comment: @SamPetrus No problem. So what do you think about this solution? Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: When I try to alert($('[name=starttime] [value=1]').text()); I do not get any text showing up, do you know why this could be?

Comment: It is hard to say if you don't give more info... Is your test inside `$(function () {});`?

Comment: No it is not, I don't know if that is the issue I will have to look and play with my code. The syntax you offered is what I needed anyway, thank you.

Comment: Have you executed the runnable snippet? As you can see, it is working fine... You have to be sure that the DOM is ready, so don't forget to encapsulate your code in `$(document).ready()`.